# Jquery fails on IE7/8/9 works with other browsers

Tags: jquery, google-maps, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

This query is failing on IE7 with error Object Expected.  In IE8/9 no error but does not work.  In all other modern browsers it work fine.

```
if (jQuery("#tabs li:eq("+jQuery("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected")+") a").attr("title")=="googlemap") {loadMap();}
    });
```

Comment: +1 for excluding IE from "modern browser"

Comment: I can't even fathom what this does. Did you try splitting it into smaller parts to see which part doesn't work?

Comment: Try simplifying the query first the above is pretty convoluted. You might also post your html so we can see what exactly you are trying to target.

Comment: Have you considered maybe breaking this down so it's actually readable?  Great job in making it compact... which really does nothing except confuse people... most people looking at that will just roll their eyes. At least show us the comments so we don't need to spend un-needed time figuring it out, or some markup. Or explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using jquery ui tabs so on that guess you might try :

```
if (jQuery("#tabs li.ui-tabs-selected a").attr("title")=="googlemap") {loadMap();}
```

Comment: The above code did not work. However, I should have provided the entire function.

Comment: I should have posted the entire code set: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('#tabs').tabs({ spinner: '<img src="images/loading.gif" height="18" border="0" alt="" />' });
 jQuery("#tabs").tabs({ cache: true });
 var $tabs = jQuery('#tabs');
 jQuery('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
  var selectedTab = ui.tab.name;
  tabCache[selectedTab] = true;
            if (jQuery("#tabs li:eq("+jQuery("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected")+") a").attr("title")=="googlemap") {loadMap();}
});